# Benchmark for fast algorithms whose task is function minimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, benchmarking, minimization

Is there a set of test functions to measure the performance (in terms of speed, maybe trading off with accuracy) of a given algorithm whose task is to find a/the global minimum of a real-valued function over a given interval? Eventually: is this problem an open problem or does there exist a theoretical best algorithm for such a task?

EDIT: there are no restrictions on the function, other that it should be bounded.

Comment: "there are no restrictions on the function": this is an unrealistic statement. In such a case the only approach is exhaustive search. Be ready for 2^64 function evaluations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no restrictions on the function except boundedness, it does not seem possible to always find its global minimum, let alone in reasonable time.

Consider the family of real-valued functions defined on [0..1]:

```
f (x0) = y0
f (x)  = 0    for all other x in [0..1]
```

For any fixed `x0 in [0..1]` and `y0 < 0`, the minimum is at `x0`.
Still, any algorithm with no prior knowledge of `x0` will have a hard time finding it.

Comment: True. Could my question have a reasonable answer if I'd tighten the constraints? (i.e. considering classes of functions almost everywhere equal, so to even out pathological cases)

Comment: @marcotrevi Yes: perhaps for continuous, smooth, or [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) functions, the question makes sense.

Comment: @marcotrevi You may have to define the domain, like real values in [0..1], as well.

Comment: Thank you. I'll post another question then, since on this one there are already your answers.

Comment: @Gassa: simple continuity doesn't really help. Think of `sin(x)+1/((x-m)²+1000)`. For a global optimum, local conditions aren't sufficient.

Comment: @Yves Daoust - What is the problem with that lady?

Answer (score 1):

Take a function that is 0 in every point where you evaluate f (x), and c for an unknown c > 0 for every point where you don't evaluate f (x). If you want it continuous, then if x is between a and b, where a and b are the neighbouring points where you evaluated f (a) and f (b), then f goes linear from f (a) = 0 to f ((a + b)/2) = c and back linear to f (b) = 0.

Clearly every time you evaluate f (x), you get a zero. Since you never evaluate anything else, your algorithm cannot conclude that the global maximum is anything but zero - which is wrong.

Comment: I suspect that that function is mathematically ill-defined, as it depends on the algorithm...

Comment: @marcotrevi We can rephrase it this way. 1. Take any algorithm. 2. Wait until it finishes execution. 3. *Then*, there exists a function (one such function is defined in the answer) on which the output of the algorithm is wrong. Therefore, no "right" algorithm exists.